# C - modify record in binary file with output to text file inserts 0s to text file

Tags: c

I have 3 functions in my C file for binary files: accadd for adding a record, view for output in a text file and modify for modifying a record.

A record has the following structure:

```
struct date
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

struct customer
{
    char name[40], acctype[10];
    int accno, age;
    double phone;
    float amount;
    struct date deposit;
} add;
```

The view function doesnt output all variables, only name, accno and phone. For example for 2 records added, this is the output file:

```
Customer's List
Customer's Name:    Account Number: Customer's Phone No:
            John                  1            777777777
            Mary                  2            111111111
```

This is fine, except when I run the modify function and output the file again:

```
Customer's List
    Customer's Name:    Account Number: Customer's Phone No:
                John                  1            999999999
                Mary                  2            111111111
                                      0                    0
                                      0                    0
                                      0                    0
                                      0                    0
                                      0                    0
                                      0                    0
                                      0                    0
                                      0                    0
                                      0                    0
                                      0                    0
                                      0                    0
                                      0                    0
                                      0                    0
```

The record got modified but I get a bunch of leading 0s. Any reason why?

The modify function:

```
void modify(char file[30]){
    FILE *view;
    int counter = 0;

    view = fopen(file, "rb+");

    if (view == NULL)
        exit(1);

    while (fread(&add, sizeof(add), 1, view) != 0)
    {
        if(add.phone==777777777){
            printf("Old phone is: %lf\n",add.phone);
            printf("New phone:\n");
            scanf("%lf", &add.phone);
            printf("New phone is: %lf\n",add.phone);
            fseek(view,sizeof(add)*counter,SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(&add,sizeof(add),1,view);
        }
        counter++;
    }
    fclose(view);

    if (counter == 0)
    {
        printf("NO RECORDS FOUND!\n");

    }
    else{
        printf("add.phone printed\n");
    }
}
```

EDIT1: The view function.

```
void view(char file[30])
{
    FILE *view,*output;
    int test = 0;
    output=fopen("output.txt", "w");
    fprintf(output,"Customer's List\n");
    fprintf(output,"\tCustomer's Name:");
    fprintf(output,"\tAccount Number:");
    fprintf(output,"\tCustomer's Phone No:\n");
    view = fopen(file, "rb");

    if (view == NULL)
        exit(1);

    while (fread(&add, sizeof(add), 1, view) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(output,"\t%16s", add.name);
        fprintf(output,"\t%15d", add.accno);
        fprintf(output,"\t%20.0f", add.phone);
        fprintf(output,"\n");
        test++;
    }
    fclose(view);
    fclose(output);

    if (test == 0)
    {
        printf("NO RECORDS FOUND!\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Output updated in file output.txt\n");
    }
}
```

EDIT2: MCVE

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void menu(void);
void accadd(void);
void modify(char file[30]); 
void view(char file[30]);

struct date
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

struct customer
{
    char name[40], acctype[10];
    int accno, age;
    double phone;
    float amount;
    struct date deposit;
} add;

void accadd(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("cus.dat", "ab+");

    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(1);

    printf("ADD RECORD\n");
    printf("Enter today's date(date/month/year) \n");
    if (scanf("%d/%d/%d", &add.deposit.day, &add.deposit.month, &add.deposit.year) != 3)
        exit(1);

    printf("Enter account number\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &add.accno) != 1)
        exit(1);

    printf("Enter customer's name\n");
    if (scanf("%s", add.name) != 1)
        exit(1);

    printf("Enter customer's age\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &add.age) != 1)
        exit(1);

    printf("Enter customer's phone num\n");
    if (scanf("%lf", &add.phone) != 1)
        exit(1);

    printf("Enter the account type(in words): \n\t 1:Current\n\t 2:Saving\n\t 3:Fixed\n");
    if (scanf("%s", add.acctype) != 1)
        exit(1);

    printf("Almost done! Just enter the amount you want to deposit: ");
    if (scanf("%f", &add.amount) != 1)
        exit(1);

    fwrite(&add, sizeof(add), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}

void view(char file[30])
{
    FILE *view,*output;
    int test = 0;
    output=fopen("output.txt", "w");
    fprintf(output,"Customer's List\n");
    fprintf(output,"\tCustomer's Name:");
    fprintf(output,"\tAccount Number:");
    fprintf(output,"\tCustomer's Phone No:\n");
    view = fopen(file, "rb");

    if (view == NULL)
        exit(1);

    while (fread(&add, sizeof(add), 1, view) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(output,"\t%16s", add.name);
        fprintf(output,"\t%15d", add.accno);
        fprintf(output,"\t%20.0f", add.phone);
        fprintf(output,"\n");
        test++;
    }
    fclose(view);
    fclose(output);

    if (test == 0)
    {
        printf("NO RECORDS FOUND!\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Output updated in file output.txt\n");
    }
}

void modify(char file[30]){
    FILE *view;
    int counter = 0;

    view = fopen(file, "rb+");

    if (view == NULL)
        exit(1);

    while (fread(&add, sizeof(add), 1, view) != 0)
    {
        if(add.phone==777777777){
            printf("Old phone is: %lf\n",add.phone);
            printf("New phone:\n");
            scanf("%lf", &add.phone);
            printf("New phone is: %lf\n",add.phone);
            fseek(view,sizeof(add)*counter,SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(&add,sizeof(add),1,view);
        }
            counter++;
    }
    fclose(view);

    if (counter == 0)
    {
        printf("NO RECORDS FOUND!\n");

    }
    else{
        printf("add.phone printed: %i\n",counter);
        printf("add length %d\n",sizeof(add));
    }
}


void menu(void)
{
    int n,account_number;
    char file[30],account_name[30];
    printf("Enter your choice 1, 2, 3\n");

    while(1){

        if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
            exit(1);

        switch (n){
        case 1:
            accadd();
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Enter the file\n");
            scanf("%s",&account_name);
            view(account_name);
            break;
        case 3:
            modify("cus.dat");
            break;
        }
        printf("Enter your choice 1, 2, 3\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    menu();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `add`? Where is it declared?

Comment: Please view the first block of code, I defined the structure there.

Comment: Ah I see it, it's a global defined when defining the structure. There's no need for global variables here, defining the variable inside the function would be recommended.

Comment: Can you paste your view() function? If I understands correctly that is the function exhibiting the strange behaviour.

Comment: Pasted the view function. Global or local variable has no bearing on the result.

Comment: I can't really see any problem with those functions, not anything that would cause the output you describe you're getting. That means it's time for you to learn how to use a debugger. Using a debugger you could step through the code, line by line, to see what it really does. While stepping through the code you can also see the values of all variables and how they change.

Comment: That's a great advice but I posted this question because I don't understand how to fix this, not that I didnt debug or at least attempt to debug the code.

Comment: Check your data file with a trusty hex viewer. Is everything in there exactly as you intended it to? Correct number of bytes per entry, correct number of entries? That said: it *should* not lead to what you get here. So also double-check **everything** for possible buffer overflows. Install `valgrind` and run your program through that.

Comment: The problem is with my counter variable, it updates until it gets to 46, that's why I have so many 0s in the output file. This only happens when I use the modify function. The other functions work fine. Any idea how to avoid it?

Comment: There must be something else you do that causes this problem, something in the code you don't show. Can you perhaps try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Added full code in EDIT 2.

Comment: There are no obvious errors in your code and I can't reproduce the error prone behaviour on my machine. Everything works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more variable printing I managed to assume after the fwrite I was stuck in writing mode so I used a

```
fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);
```

to get back to read mode. I don't know if this explanation is accurate, but it fixed my issue.

I also simplified my modify function to be clearer.

```
void modify(char file[30]){
    FILE *view;
    int counter = 0;

    view = fopen(file, "rb+");

    if (view == NULL)
        exit(1);

    while (fread(&add, sizeof(add), 1, view) != 0)
    {

        if(add.phone==777777777){
            add.phone=145;
            fseek(view,sizeof(add)*counter,SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(&add,sizeof(add),1,view);
            fseek(view,0,SEEK_SET);
        }
            counter++;
    }
    fclose(view);
}
```

I hope to be of use to anyone wanting to modify a record from a binary file.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that your fread() method misbehaves in some way. To debug this you might need to capture the return value so it is easy to inspect in the debugger. So change the view() function to do something like:

```
void view(char file[30])
{
    FILE *view,*output;
    size_t ret;
    int test = 0;

    /* ... */

    while ((ret = fread(&add, sizeof(add), 1, view)) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(output,"\t%16s", add.name);
        fprintf(output,"\t%15d", add.accno);
        fprintf(output,"\t%20.0f", add.phone);
        fprintf(output,"\n");
        test++;
    }
    fclose(view);
    fclose(output);

    /* ... */
}
```

The in your debugger set a breakpoint on the first line on the loop and inspect the ret variable in each iteration. For the two expected iterations the value of ret should be 1, but what is it for the iterations printing zeroes?

One possibility is that it in some cases choses to signal errors by returning -1 (yeah, that would be broken). In that case you could change your conditional from testing for a non-zero to testing for the actual return value fread() should have when reading 1 record.

Comment: The problem is in the modify function. If you add 2 records like in the first post (chose option 1), one with phone = 777777777 and the other without, then print it using option 2, you get file output.txt. This file is good, the output is fine, only 2 records in the file. But when you modify it, you get those strange inputs in the file.